# How to get limited no. of data in recycler view

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am fetching data using API. For that I am using Retrofit2 and RxJava2. The data is fetching successfully but I don't want to show whole items. I just want to show 5 items in a list.

Below is my code:

```
 Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
     ApiService myApi = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
     myApi.getHindiNews(data).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                             .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                             .subscribe(new Observer<List<HomeHindiModel>>() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onNext(List<HomeHindiModel> homeHindiModels) {

                                     if(homeHindiModels.size() > 0){

                                             homeHindiList.addAll(homeHindiModels);
                                             homeHindiAdapter = new HomeHindiAdapter(homeHindiList,getActivity());
                                             hindiRecycler.setAdapter(homeHindiAdapter);
                                        
                                     }
                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onComplete() {

                                 }
                             });
```

How can I get desired output?

Comment: You are using addAll instead of this use a for loop and then according to your need set your limit and the add list in your adapter, with this you can add more data later on according to your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

into `RecyclerView` `Adapter` class

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(homeHindiList != null) {
        if(homeHindiList.size() > 5) {
            return 5;
        } else 
            return homeHindiList.size();
    } else 
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would extend this by checking if the data returned is greater than 5, e.g if(data.size() > 5) return 5; else return data.size(); you could get nullpointers if list size is less than 5 @Digvijay

Answer (score 2):

When you get data from remote resources then you can push only 5 items into your data source which you are going to send an adapter.

```
 Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
ApiService myApi = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
myApi.getHindiNews(data).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Observer<List<HomeHindiModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<HomeHindiModel> homeHindiModels) {

                if(homeHindiModels.size() > 0){

                  homeHindiList.addAll(homeHindiModels.subList(0, 5));

                  //  homeHindiList.addAll(homeHindiModels);
                    homeHindiAdapter = new HomeHindiAdapter(homeHindiList,getActivity());
                    hindiRecycler.setAdapter(homeHindiAdapter);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding all the items from homeHindiModels list, you can use the sublist method of arraylist to add only the required items. Here first param indicates the starting index from where the sublist would create and the second param indicates the number of items.

```
homeHindiList.addAll(homeHindiModels.subList(0, 5));
```